# Как вывести результаты фильтра на странице списка товаров?

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет. Моя задача, вывести фильтр на главной странице и вывести результаты на странице СПИСКА ТОВАРОВ, компоненте КАТАЛОГ.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести результаты фильтра на странице СПИСКА ТОВАРОВ(catalog.section в комплексном компоненте catalog) до этого я пытался в ручную писать раздел в форме где action атрибут пример так (catalog/kamen тут php код) KAMEN это раздел, результаты выводит. Мне нужно чтобы разделы сами автомат формировались, как это можно реализовать ? Заранее спасибо. На странице СПИСКА КАТАЛОГА есть фильтр.

https://camouf.ru/blog-note/2502/?sphrase_id=16407 - Если что тут есть видео-урок, вывод фильтра на главной но, результаты выводит на другой странице.

Comment: Какие параметры для фильтрации?

Comment: Использую в основном параметр СПИСОК - отображается как Checkbox. Вы это имели ввиду ?